# How to access WebDAV shared folder on Mac OS X Server

Tags: macos, osx-server, file-sharing, webdav

Mac OS X Server supports WebDAV and allows iPhones/iPads to connect, store and retrieve files.

While Mac OS X can access WebDAV servers from the Finder using "Connect to Server" (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) attempting to connect to the root of a Mac OS X server or any other assumed location results in an error:

> There was a problem connecting to the server “theserver.domain.com”.
>   Check the server name or IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator

I can only guess that there is some special URL/URI that is necessary but what?

Comment: What version of OS are you running on the server?

Comment: macOS 10.12.1, was 10.12.0 at the point of this post

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it partially works.

The server's WebDAV interface is presented from a virtual directory "webdav". If your server is at

```
https://theserver.domain.com
```

then the beginning of your WebDAV access starts at:

```
https://theserver.domain.com/webdav/
```

This will typically be your "home folder" if the server is setup to offer users home folders.

And while it does not represent your actual directory structure , all other shared volumes are tacked on to the end of that. So if you mark a folder as shared with "WebDAV" thusly:

[image: WebDAV Shared Folder]

then the access would be:

```
https://theserver.domain.com/webdav/swap/
```

Caveats:

- URI is case sensitive
- username aliases are not respected, you must use the "short name" for login, even from the Mac OS X Finder's friendly login dialog
- Wiki storage access with WebDAV ... still not clear on the URI